# open source license scanner (heuristic, regular expression matches in subdirs)

Tags: php, regex, perl, licensing

Assume you have a small collection of WebCMS assembled, subdirs in ~/www/test/ or so. And now you want to quickly/crude scan and detect the license in each project.

Is there a simple grep/perl/regex scanner which can guess the used licenses? Doesn't need to be exact or reliable, just for getting a rough overview, and just needs to inspect directory-wise.

Comment: Considering that each project declares its license in its own way, something like this would prob be fairly error prone (I know you used the term heuristic so you realize that).  You could search for an `@license` doc tag, and if that fails try to match on other criteria...  But it's not going to be trivial if you want it reliable...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Yes, it hardly can be done reliably. I've just tried a few simple egrep "\w+ License" \*/* scans, but even that only gives me an approximation for half of them. The only sensible way seems to be looking for license\*, copying\* or readme* files (and case-insensitively). But even then you'd still need a prepared list of guesstimate regexpressions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ohcount](http://www.ohloh.net/p/ohcount), the tool http://ohloh.net/ uses to extract various metrics like number of lines per programming language from source code, also happens to have quite a lot of seemingly good heuristics to detect licenses. I haven't used it myself, but it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: apt-get install ohcount && echo ":)"